# How to Find the Accurate Memory Usage of Python Object?

Tags: python, memory

Is there a way to find the accurate size of an object regardless of implementation?

sys.getsizeof is not what I'm looking for. For example, if there's a dict, I would like to know the total size of the dict and its items, not just the dict object.

Iterating through all key/value is also not what I'm looking for. Say I have implemented a container that can be used like a normal dict, but actually reads data from a local file and only keeps some data in an LRU cache. In that situation I would like to know the size of the cache, not the file.

The most accurate way to describe it would probably be: how much memory is freed up if I del the object.

If I have an object that keeps a lot of references to imported modules (bad example but anyways), when I del the object these modules would not be removed from memory, so I'm not counting them as memory occupied by this object.

Also, this object might be implemented in C++.

I apologize if the question is not well-defined. Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no general solution that's as accurate as what you're asking for. There are tools that *try*, like [`pympler.asizeof`](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but nothing gets anywhere near as reliable as what you're asking for.

First, let's address this part:

> The most accurate way to describe it would probably be: how much memory is freed up if I del the object.

This is not possible to compute in general, and even if it was, you'd probably find it's not what you're really looking for.

It's not possible, because there's no way to figure out what other objects will get freed if an object gets freed. You can try to traverse the object graph with [`gc.get_referents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents) and [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount) and try to figure out what objects are only reachable through a given object, but the problem is that `gc.get_referents` doesn't report all references an object owns. `gc.get_referents` only shows references an object reports to the GC system, and an object can leave out references that are guaranteed not to participate in a reference cycle.

There is no way to get *all* the references an object owns, so there is no way to figure out what other objects will die when an object dies.

As for this probably not being what you really want, the problem is that "non-owning" references to an object's "insides" keep those parts alive if the object dies. For example, in the following code:

```
l = [[None]*10 for i in range(10)]

# I'm deliberately not looping over l directly, to avoid generating extra references to l.
for i in range(10):
    subl = l[i]
    for j in range(10):
        subl[j] = whatever()
```

If you were to delete `l` after `subl` is assigned, the `subl` reference would keep one of the sublists alive. This means that less memory would be freed. It probably doesn't make sense to treat `l`'s memory usage as smaller while the `subl` reference exists, but the "how much memory is freed up if I del the object" standard does exactly that.

---

Libraries like Pympler don't try to apply this standard, but they're still unreliable.

For one thing, they *still* can't get all the references an object owns. They can special-case some common data types, but they can't special-case everything, so there will still be references they miss.

The second problem is that they can't tell whether a reference means the referred-to object should be considered "part of" the object that owns the reference. `pympler.asizeof` has some simple heuristics for references to exclude, [documented](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asizeof.html) under "Ignored Objects", but these heuristics are things like "don't include type objects" or "don't include a function's globals". It can't detect things like "these graph node objects own their neighbor lists, but they *don't* own their neighbors".

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on Python, but have you tried using a lib like Pympler ?
I have used it once in the past and it provided some tools for memory profiling etc. Although I'm not quite sure if it gives tools for exact memory size.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's really no accurate or general solution in Python, keeping in mind that memory measurements can be influenced by various factors, and the numbers you see might not be exact due to Python's memory management mechanisms and other factors.

However, using tools like `memory_profiler` can still provide valuable insights into how memory is being used in your code. Here's some example of how you can use the `memory_profiler` package in Python:

#### Example 1

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def main(my_obj):
    print("Memory used by: ",my_obj)
    print("Memory used before delete: {}".format(memory_usage()/(1024*1024)))
    del my_obj
    print("Memory used after delete: {}".format(memory_usage()/(1024*1024)))

def memory_usage():
    import psutil
    process = psutil.Process()
    return process.memory_info().rss

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main({'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'})
```

Output:

```
Memory used by:  {'key': 'value', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
Memory used before delete: 42.5234375
Memory used after delete: 42.5234375

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     3     42.5 MiB     42.5 MiB           1   @profile
     4                                         def main(my_obj):
     5     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print("Memory used by: ",my_obj)
     6     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print("Memory used before delete: {}".format(memory_usage()/(1024*1024)))
     7     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del my_obj
     8     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print("Memory used after delete: {}".format(memory_usage()/(1024*1024)))
```

#### Example 2

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def main_func():
    import random
    arr1 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100000)]
    arr2 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100000)]
    arr3 = [arr1[i]+arr2[i] for i in range(100000)]
    del arr1
    del arr2
    tot = sum(arr3)
    del arr3
    print(tot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_func()
```

Output:

```
Filename: /dumpy.py
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    15     42.7 MiB     42.7 MiB           1   @profile
    16                                         def main_func():
    17     42.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       import random
    18     43.9 MiB      1.2 MiB      100003       arr1 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100000)]
    19     44.7 MiB      0.8 MiB      100003       arr2 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100000)]
    20     45.4 MiB      0.8 MiB      100003       arr3 = [arr1[i]+arr2[i] for i in range(100000)]
    21     44.8 MiB     -0.7 MiB           1       del arr1
    22     44.0 MiB     -0.8 MiB           1       del arr2
    23     44.0 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tot = sum(arr3)
    24     43.2 MiB     -0.8 MiB           1       del arr3
    25     43.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(tot)
```

#### Example 3

```
from memory_profiler import profile
class MyClass:
    
    @profile
    def __init__(self, data):
        import tensorflow
        print("Memory used by: my_class_obj")
        print("Tensorflow Version: ", tensorflow.__version__)
        self.data = data
        import random
        arr1 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(200000)]
        arr2 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(200000)]
        arr3 = [arr1[i]+arr2[i] for i in range(100000)]
        del arr1
        del arr2
        tot = sum(arr3)
        del arr3
        print(tot)
        
my_obj = MyClass([1, 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
Memory used by: my_class_obj
Tensorflow Version:  2.13.0
1098606
Filename: /dumpy.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    33     42.3 MiB     42.3 MiB           1       @profile
    34                                             def __init__(self, data):
    35    463.1 MiB    420.8 MiB           1           import tensorflow
    36    463.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           print("Memory used by: my_class_obj")
    37    463.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           print("Tensorflow Version: ", tensorflow.__version__)
    38    463.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           self.data = data
    39    463.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           import random
    40    464.6 MiB      1.5 MiB      200003           arr1 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(200000)]
    41    466.0 MiB      1.4 MiB      200003           arr2 = [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(200000)]
    42    466.8 MiB      0.9 MiB      100003           arr3 = [arr1[i]+arr2[i] for i in range(100000)]
    43    466.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del arr1
    44    466.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del arr2
    45    466.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           tot = sum(arr3)
    46    466.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           del arr3
    47    466.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           print(tot)
```

#### Example 4

```
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile(precision=4)
def main_func():
    import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_excel("segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results.xlsx")
    df2 = df1.copy()
    df3 = pd.read_excel("segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results.xlsx")
    df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
    del df1
    del df2
    del df3
    del df4
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_func()
```

Output:

```
Filename: /home/arrafi/dumpy.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
     3  42.6641 MiB  42.6641 MiB           1   @profile(precision=4)
     4                                         def main_func():
     5 129.7344 MiB  87.0703 MiB           1       import pandas as pd
     6 145.8594 MiB  16.1250 MiB           1       df1 = pd.read_excel("segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results/day1_segmentation_results.xlsx")
     7 145.8594 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       df2 = df1.copy()
     8 146.1094 MiB   0.2500 MiB           1       df3 = pd.read_excel("segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results/day3_segmentation_results.xlsx")
     9 146.6094 MiB   0.5000 MiB           1       df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
    10 146.6094 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       del df1
    11 146.6094 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       del df2
    12 146.6094 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       del df3
    13 146.6094 MiB   0.0000 MiB           1       del df4
```